# Is it possible to set maximum allowed ios version

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, deployment

We have 2 big applications ready for app store submission but they were created for iOS 4.x and are not properly tested for iOS 5. There are some definite glitches when running the app on iOS 5. Testing for iOS 5 would take 2 3 weeks more.

Is it possible to restrict the app to devices with iOS 4.x or lower (like we can set the minimum required iOS version).
We can then follow up with an update which would support iOS 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple are pretty aggressive when pushing new versions of the OS, so I think the answer is no.

But, even if the answer was yes I'd argue that it's not a good thing to do anyway. A large percentage of users have already upgraded to iOS 5 (and early adopters are the ones most likely to buy or download apps). Beta's of iOS5 have been available since June so I'm surprised that you're only now testing with the newer OS.